# Writing multiple strings into csv from python

Tags: python

I have written a python web scraper and would like to output the data strings I have gotten into a csv/excel file. So far, I have a for loop that accesses multiple database websites and stores the data in a string. I would like to pop out these strings each time I complete the web scraping before moving onto the next page.

Someone suggested to create a whole repository of them or a dictionary and then reference it. I tried implementing it, but my code instead returns me a the data in one cell instead of spanning multiple cells because I have a header at the top that separates the data into my desired attributes.

```
Substances = []
Whole_list = []
f = open(filename)  # chemtest.txt 
for sub in f: 
    Substances.append(sub)
    print sub

for substance in Substances: 
    #some logic 
    names1 = [data ]
    Whole_list.append(names1)

with open('chemtest.csv', 'wb') as myfile:  #creates new chemtest.csv
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(Whole_list)
```

So far I'm running through 2 websites as a test and my outputs are:

```
names1 = ['Acetaldehyde', 'Acetaldehyde', '75-07-0', 'GO1N1ZPR3B', 'CC=O']
Whole_list = [['Acetaldehyde', 'Acetaldehyde', '75-07-0', 'GO1N1ZPR3B', 'CC=O']]
names1 = ['Acetone', 'Acetone', '67-64-1', '1364PS73AF', '=O']
Whole_list = [['Acetaldehyde', 'Acetaldehyde', '75-07-0', 'GO1N1ZPR3B', 'CC=O'], ['Acetone', 'Acetone', '67-64-1', '1364PS73AF', '=O']]
```

What is wrong with my method exactly and how can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (note the *s* at the end). `writerow` is for writing one line at a time.

```
wr.writerows(Whole_list)
```

As a side note, capitalized variable names are usually reserved to classes, so prefer `whole_list`.

Comment: This, and make sure you're using the appropriate delimiter - if all your values appear in one cell, then your Excel version might be expecting something other than a comma between columns - European Excels expect semicolons, for example. Try setting `delimiter=";"` when creating the `writer` object.

Comment: Okay, thanks! @TimPietzcker: That's interesting. I'll be sure to keep that in mind. Thanks!